# $EDITOR environment variable leads to "command not found"

Tags: shell, environment-variables, zsh, zshrc

I want my default editor to be `TERM=xterm-16color emacs -nw` but when I set the `$EDITOR` environment variable in my .zshrc I get a "command not found" error when I run `$EDITOR`

What works (when added to .zshrc):

- `export EDITOR=emacs`
- `export EDITOR=(emacs -nw)`

But that's not what I want.

What doesn't work:

- `export EDITOR=(TERM=xterm-16color emacs -nw)`
- `export EDITOR="TERM=xterm-16color emacs -nw"`
- `export EDITOR='TERM=xterm-16color emacs -nw'`

I don't know what to do... Just running `TERM=xterm-16color emacs -nw` launches the editor correctly, I don't understand what zsh doesn't like about my exports.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You probably should just `export TERM=xterm-16color`, but if for some reason you don't want that, you could do `EDITOR="sh -c 'TERM=xterm-16color emacs -nw'"`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks for the answer. Exporting TERM instead of EDITOR works for my purpose (as a dirty fix). As for your other proposition, I still get a "command not found". (This makes absolutely no sense...)

Comment: @Dario : The lines which don't work, assign to an *array* variable _EDITOR_, because `VAR=(....)` is an array assignment. Maybe you want a function for running your editor?

Answer (score 1):

When you run `TERM=xterm-16color emacs -nw`, all that does is run `emacs -nw` with TERM set to `xterm-16color` in the environment.  Almost certainly what you want is for TERM to be set appropriately in your environment. You probably want to do something like:

```
export TERM=xterm-16color
export EDITOR='emacs -nw'
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the job. But it doesn't explain what sorcery is happening here. Why is ```export EDITOR='emacs -nw'``` wrong? This too yields a "command not found" when running ```$EDITOR```

Comment: Or why does ```export EDITOR=(emacs -nw)``` work but not ```export EDITOR=(TERM=xterm-16color emacs -nw)```?

Comment: If you run `$EDITOR`, the shell looks for an executable named `emacs -nw` in your PATH rather than looking for an executable named `emacs` that it will call with an argument of `-nw`.  But you could run `eval $EDITOR`

Comment: When you set `EDITOR=(TERM=xterm16color emacs -nw)`, the shell looks for an executable named `TERM=xterm16color` rather than looking for an executable named `emacs` that is run with TERM assigned in its environment.

Comment: Ok, now I get that I am not supposed to run ```$EDITOR``` alone but that I am supposed to ```eval``` it. Weirdly, now my terminal doesn't even allow me to ```export EDITOR="TERM=xterm-16color emacs -nw"``` and tells me "export: not valid in this context: emacs -nw". But if I could, then ```eval $EDITOR``` would work, right?

Comment: `EDITOR` isn't meant to be used by the shell alone; it's used by *any* program that might fork an editor. You can't export an array.